# Conflict between xml and yml in logback configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, logback

My spring boot application uses simple logback configuration in yml:

```
logging:
  file: /logs/mylog.log
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        web: WARN
      hibernate: WARN
```

It works fine until adding a third party artifact that contains its own logback.xml file. If logback.xml is on the classpath, logback ignores yml configuration. I can create my own logback.xml in order to solve the problem, but it requires to manage profiles in both xml and yml files.

Is there a way to configure logback to use my yml file and ignore other xml files?

Thanks

Comment: By default logging configuration files from the root of the classpath will be loaded. Using the `logging.config` change that default location to some weird place in the classpath and you should be fine

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, logging.config expects for xml file, not for yml. My yml is on root of the classpath, but logback prefers logback.xml file from third party jar rather than my spring boot yml.

Comment: Exception was: ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException: Unexpected filename extension of file [file:application.yml]. Should be either .groovy or .xml